# mat-menu appears on left click instead of right click as desired

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-tree in that I want to right click the node and show mat-menu,but the left click shows the menu,how to disable the left click without disabling the click event and how do I achieve the right click menu only.
html

```
<mat-tree #treeSelector [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle 
          (click)="selectednode = node" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)"   [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight':selectednode === node  }">
          <mat-menu #menu1="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="add(node)">Add</button>
            <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="selectednode && selectednode.id ===0 ? false: true"
              (click)="remove(node)">Remove</button>
          </mat-menu>
          <mat-icon class="folder-icon-spacing" fontSet="far" [fontIcon]="'fa-folder'">
          </mat-icon>
          <div class="node-format item-font">
            {{node.name}} </div>
          <div class="align-setproperties item-font" (click)="showProperties(node)">Set Properties</div>
        </mat-tree-node>
        <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">
          <div class="mat-tree-node" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)"  (click)="selectednode = node"
            [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight':selectednode === node  }">
            <!-- <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name"> -->
            <mat-icon class="folder-icon-spacing" fontSet="far"
              [fontIcon]="treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'fa-folder-open' : 'fa-folder'">
            </mat-icon>
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror chevron-color">
              {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
            <!-- </button> -->
            <div class="node-format item-font">
              {{node.name}} </div>
            <div class="align-setproperties item-font" (click)="showProperties(node)">Set Properties</div>
          </div>
          <div [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)" role="group">
            <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
          <mat-menu #menu1="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="add(node)">Add</button>
            <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="selectednode && selectednode.id ===0 ? false: true"
              (click)="remove(node)">Remove</button>
          </mat-menu>
        </mat-nested-tree-node>
      </mat-tree>
```

TS partial code

```
export class MytreeComponent  {
   // reference to the MatMenuTrigger in the DOM 
   @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) matMenuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  onRightClick(event:Event){
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("Right Clicked");
    this.matMenuTrigger.openMenu();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the below snippet to solve it

```
   <div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed"
                  [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
                  [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y"
                  [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu">
      </div>
```

Refered this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-context-menu?file=app%2Fcontext-menu-example.html) link